# I cannot connect to the special "Sharing Only" user that macOS creates with the sole purpose of sharing files

Tags: macos, ftp, network-shares, sftp, users

I am attempting to access the Sharing Only user via SFTP through my Wi-Fi but I get the errors on the pictures. I have repeatedly confirmed that my password and user names are correct.

The apps I use, Koder, Documents by Readdle, and Files by Apple, all give me the same error for this user account on my 2021 Macbook Pro. I am able to access my Administrator account and other users on my Macbook Pro via SFTO on Wi-Fi, but not the Sharing Only user.

Additional info:
I managed to connect to the Sharing Only user using the Files app on the iPhone by refreshing my Sharing Only user password, but I still cannot connect using Readdle Document or Koder. I am on my own WI-FI, and using the same user info on the 3 apps.

What could be causing this issue?

"Sharing Only" User:

[image: "Sharing Only" User]

SFTP Error Message for "Sharing Only" User:
[image: SFTP Error Message for "Sharing Only" User]

Comment: @Destroy666  I was not allowed to embed the pictures myself, but you did it. This looks much nicer. That is a fine edit, thank you very much.